# Cross Compile Cannot Link Curl and Crypto

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, g++, cross-compiling

I installed arm-linux-gnueabihf via `sudo apt-get install arm-linux-gnueabihf` and i want to do cross compile for Raspberry Pi.
My make file is like that:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ *.cpp *.h b64.c -o file -lcurl -lcrypto -lpthread -lssl
```

and an error occured like that:

```
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl

/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
```

Also I tried to link with  `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so` but it is still same error.

Also i don't understand why libssl a is linked but others do not.

How can I link these libraries to arm-linux-gnueabihf?
Thank you.

Comment: Two problems: The first is that the `-L` option is to specify a *directory* to search for libraries. The second is that you seem to want to link the *host* library with your program, which will not work since it will not match your target.

Comment: Thank you so much for fast reply. How can i link the host library to my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot link x86-64 bit libraries with arm-linux-gnueabihd.
You need to get gnueabihf libraries of curl and crypto.
One way: cross-compile curl and crypto libraries, use -L to specify directories where cross-compiled libcurl.so and libcrypto.so for gnuaebihf machine reside.
Another way: copy libcurl.so and libcrypto.so from raspberrypi onto your computer, specify directory where they reside with -L and try to compile, it should work.
ssl and pthread is linked, because you provide ssl and pthread libraries compiled for gnueabihf architecture. Look in /usr/arm-* for those files, probably in /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib.
Generally, for beginners, just compile your program on your raspberry pi (with curl and crypto installed), it will spare you much trouble.

The line `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so` is invalid. You don't specify file using -L command line, you specify directory which contains libcurl.so. Also you specified directory with x86-64 architecture specific libraries while using gnueabihf compiler, they will not work, they are not compatible, no. You cannot link `x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so` or any x86-64 library with a gnueabihf program.
The whole idea of crosscompiling is that you compile for another architecture. You don't mix those architectures, as they are not compitable with each other, just like you can't run x86-64 program on you raspberry pi, and you can't run a rapberry pi program on you computer. The machine codes of two architectures are not compatible with each other. 
When you compile a program for gnueabihf architecture, you need to link gnuabihf libraries and use gnuabihf object files and use a compiler that will generate gnueabihf specific machine code. When you compile program for x86-64 machine, you need to link x86-64 libraries and use x86-86 object files and use a compiler that will generate x86-64 machine code.
Probably it may be also worth to you, use [file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command to determine file type. You may run `file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so` to see that this libcurl.so is a x86-64 shared object.